# Does Rails Devise gem uses cookies for authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

It would be great to have a supporting doc for the same.

Comment: Any details here? How should it use cookies for auth? As far as I know - you could try to take a look at `:rememberable` strategy, but for what reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

Devise is built on top of [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden), which uses the session. I don't see any easy way to use cookies for authentication (although you may use rememberable to keep it recorded between sessions). Sessions are enabled by cookies, so it uses the cookies indirectly.

Comment: The Session *does* use a cookie by default.

Comment: Ok, I've changed to explain it better.

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming the question can be restated as "Does Devise use a cookie to keep track of your session after authentication."  If so, the answer is yes.

To test this, clear your cookies, log in and then check your cookies again.  You'll see one for your website named after your app.

@Rodrigo, sessions are enabled by cookies.  That's how the session can follow you through multiple pages.  HTTP is inherently stateless.  Cookies allow you to save state.

Comment: do you know what is the name of the cookie that devise uses to maintain user information, i am trying to debug a issue and what to know is the correct cookie is sent in my load balanced application.